# Classes applied to HTML5 elements not getting applied in IE8 using Modernizr

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8, modernizr

I'm using a custom build of Modernizr that includes html5shiv v3.7

In my markup I have classes applied to HTML5 elements like so:

```
<article class="white_text">This text is white</article>
```

and the CSS would be something like:

```
.white_text { color: white; }
```

This works as expected in all browsers that I need to test, but the attributes of the class "white_text" are not applied in IE8. I can confirm that html5shiv is working properly since

```
article { DISPLAY: block }
```

appears in the  of the document in IE8.

In order to apply styling to HTML5 elements in IE8, I need to rewrite the markup to surround the elements with non-semantic tags such as .

Is there a problem with how I'm implementing Modernizr?

SOLUTION (thanks to Pinal):
The Modernizr script must be placed in the head of the document.

Comment: Have a doctype on your page?

Comment: html5shiv must be on the top of head, before all scripts and stylesheets. Isn't it?

Comment: That was the problem. I had Modernizr loading before the closing body tag. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need to separately include html5shiv, because Modernizr has actually included it since version 2.0:

Comment: Thanks, Code - I was aware of that. Pinal provided the solution I needed. My fault for not reading the documentation closely enough ;)

Comment: @Pinal You should post your comment as an answer so it can be easily found for everyone. OP: You should accept said answer after it is posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html5shiv must be on the top of head, before all scripts and stylesheets.